# Lexical analyzer gives undefined error for yylineno

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

Im pretty new to compiler design. im trying to take the first step in lexical analyzer trying to run the following code.

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "symboltable.h"
#include "tokens.h"

entry_t** symbol_table;
entry_t** constant_table;
int cmnt_strt = 0;


%}
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
ws  [ \t\r\f\v]+
identifier (_|{letter})({letter}|{digit}|_){0,31}
hex [0-9a-f]

 /* Exclusive states */
%x CMNT
%x PREPROC

%%
  /* Keywords*/
"int"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,INT);}
"long"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,LONG);}
"long long"                       {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,LONG_LONG);}
"short"                           {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,SHORT);}
"signed"                          {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,SIGNED);}
"unsigned"                        {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,UNSIGNED);}
"for"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,FOR);}
"break"                           {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,BREAK);}
"continue"                        {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,CONTINUE);}
"if"                              {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,IF);}
"else"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,ELSE);}
"return"                          {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,RETURN);}

{identifier}                      {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n", yytext,IDENTIFIER);
                                  insert( symbol_table,yytext,IDENTIFIER );}
{ws}                              ;
[+\-]?[0][x|X]{hex}+[lLuU]?        {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n", yytext,HEX_CONSTANT);
                                                    insert( constant_table,yytext,HEX_CONSTANT);}
[+\-]?{digit}+[lLuU]?              {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n", yytext,DEC_CONSTANT);
                                                    insert( constant_table,yytext,DEC_CONSTANT);}
"/*"                              {cmnt_strt = yylineno; BEGIN CMNT;}
<CMNT>.|{ws}                      ;
<CMNT>\n                          {yylineno++;}
<CMNT>"*/"                        {BEGIN INITIAL;}
<CMNT>"/*"                        {printf("Line %3d: Nested comments are not valid!\n",yylineno);}
<CMNT><<EOF>>                     {printf("Line %3d: Unterminated comment\n", cmnt_strt); yyterminate();}
^"#include"                       {BEGIN PREPROC;}
<PREPROC>"<"[^<>\n]+">"            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,HEADER_FILE);}
<PREPROC>{ws}                       ;
<PREPROC>\"[^"\n]+\"              {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,HEADER_FILE);}
<PREPROC>\n                       {yylineno++; BEGIN INITIAL;}
<PREPROC>.                        {printf("Line %3d: Illegal header file format \n",yylineno);}
"//".*                            ;

\"[^\"\n]*\"     {

  if(yytext[yyleng-2]=='\\') /* check if it was an escaped quote */
  {
    yyless(yyleng-1);       /* push the quote back if it was escaped */
    yymore();
  }
  else
  insert( constant_table,yytext,STRING);
 }

\"[^\"\n]*$                     {printf("Line %3d: Unterminated string %s\n",yylineno,yytext);}
{digit}+({letter}|_)+           {printf("Line %3d: Illegal identifier name %s\n",yylineno,yytext);}
\n                              {yylineno++;}
"--"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,DECREMENT);}
"++"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,INCREMENT);}
"->"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,PTR_SELECT);}
"&&"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,LOGICAL_AND);}
"||"                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,LOGICAL_OR);}
"<="                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,LS_THAN_EQ);}
">="                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,GR_THAN_EQ);}
"=="                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,EQ);}
"!="                            {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,NOT_EQ);}
";"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,DELIMITER);}
"{"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,OPEN_BRACES);}
"}"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,CLOSE_BRACES);}
","                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,COMMA);}
"="                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,ASSIGN);}
"("                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,OPEN_PAR);}
")"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,CLOSE_PAR);}
"["                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,OPEN_SQ_BRKT);}
"]"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,CLOSE_SQ_BRKT);}
"-"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,MINUS);}
"+"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,PLUS);}
"*"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,STAR);}
"/"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,FW_SLASH);}
"%"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,MODULO);}
"<"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,LS_THAN);}
">"                             {printf("\t%-30s : %3d\n",yytext,GR_THAN);}
.                               {printf("Line %3d: Illegal character %s\n",yylineno,yytext);}

%%

int yywrap(){ return 1;}

int main()
{
  yyin=fopen("testcases/test-case-1.c","r");
  symbol_table=create_table();
  constant_table=create_table();
  yylex();
  printf("\n\tSymbol table");
  display(symbol_table);
  printf("\n\tConstants Table");
  display(constant_table);
  printf("NOTE: Please refer tokens.h for token meanings\n");
}
```

I tried to run it using:

```
flex lexer.l
gcc lex.yy.c -o lexrun
```

This gives me an error as

```
lexer.l: In function 'yylex':
lexer.l:46:14: error: 'yylineno' undeclared (first use in this function)
 "/*"                              {cmnt_strt = yylineno; BEGIN CMNT;}
              ^~~~~~~~
lexer.l:46:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I tried many things on the net such as adding

```
extern int yylineno;
```

This started giving another error as

```
 undefined reference to `yylineno'
```

I have installed Flex version 2.5.4 and runs this in Vscode.
Any clarification to overcome this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want flex to track line numbers you need to add

```
%option yylineno
```

to your flex prologue.

I also suggest the following:

- ```
  %option noinput nounput
  ```

  which will allow you to compile the generated scanner without compiler warnings (***Always*** compile with `-Wall`, even generated code, and fix whatever warnings are reported.)
- ```
  %option noyywrap
  ```

  which avoids the need to define `yywrap`
- ```
  %option  nodefualt
  ```

  which will warn you if you don't have a rule for every possible input.

---

As a final note, `extern int yylineno;` can't work, since `extern` means "this variable is defined in a different translation unit", and there is no other translation unit in your code. I presume that you found that in the discussion of a different file intended to be linked together with the scanner. (If the place you found that suggests putting the `extern` declaration in a `.l` file, you need to discard it as a source of information.)

If this is the first time you've attempted to write a C application with more than one source file, you should probably take a few minutes to review how linking multiple files works in C. That will save you a lot of frustration later.

Comment: It fixed my error and thanks for the time taken in educating me!