# Parser gives a unknown type name error for entry_t

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm editing my first parser and I'm very new to compiler design. I'm using a **hashtable** to store tokens. I have created a struct called **struct_t** in my **symboletable.h** file.

When I try to create a new **entry_t** in .y file under %union to be used in **lex** file. But it gives an error in compile time as:

> parser.y:17:2: error: unknown type name 'entry_t'   entry_t** entry;

parser.y file :

```
%{
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "symboltable.h"

    entry_t** symbol_table;
    entry_t** constant_table;

    double Evaluate (double lhs_value,int assign_type,double rhs_value);
    int current_dtype;
    int yyerror(char *msg);
%}

%union
{
    double dval;
    entry_t** entry;
    int ival;
}

%token <entry> IDENTIFIER

 /* Constants */
%token <dval> DEC_CONSTANT HEX_CONSTANT
%token STRING

 /* Logical and Relational operators */
%token LOGICAL_AND LOGICAL_OR LS_EQ GR_EQ EQ NOT_EQ

 /* Short hand assignment operators */
%token MUL_ASSIGN DIV_ASSIGN MOD_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN SUB_ASSIGN
%token LEFT_ASSIGN RIGHT_ASSIGN AND_ASSIGN XOR_ASSIGN OR_ASSIGN
%token INCREMENT DECREMENT

 /* Data types */
%token SHORT INT LONG LONG_LONG SIGNED UNSIGNED CONST

 /* Keywords */
%token IF FOR WHILE CONTINUE BREAK RETURN

%type <dval> expression
%type <dval> sub_expr
%type <dval> constant
%type <dval> unary_expr
%type <dval> arithmetic_expr
%type <dval> assignment_expr
%type <entry> lhs
%type <ival> assign_op

%start starter

%left ','
%right '='
%left LOGICAL_OR
%left LOGICAL_AND
%left EQ NOT_EQ
%left '<' '>' LS_EQ GR_EQ
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%right '!'


%nonassoc UMINUS
%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE
%nonassoc ELSE


%%

 /* Program is made up of multiple builder blocks. */
starter: starter builder
             |builder;

 /* Each builder block is either a function or a declaration */
builder: function|
       declaration;

 /* This is how a function looks like */
function: type IDENTIFIER '(' argument_list ')' compound_stmt;

 /* Now we will define a grammar for how types can be specified */

type :data_type pointer
    |data_type;

pointer: '*' pointer
    |'*'
    ;

data_type :sign_specifier type_specifier
    |type_specifier
    ;

sign_specifier :SIGNED
    |UNSIGNED
    ;

type_specifier :INT                    {current_dtype = INT;}
    |SHORT INT                         {current_dtype = SHORT;}
    |SHORT                             {current_dtype = SHORT;}
    |LONG                              {current_dtype = LONG;}
    |LONG INT                          {current_dtype = LONG;}
    |LONG_LONG                         {current_dtype = LONG_LONG;}
    |LONG_LONG INT                     {current_dtype = LONG_LONG;}
    ;

 /* grammar rules for argument list */
 /* argument list can be empty */
argument_list :arguments
    |
    ;
 /* arguments are comma separated TYPE ID pairs */
arguments :arguments ',' arg
    |arg
    ;

 /* Each arg is a TYPE ID pair */
arg :type IDENTIFIER
   ;

 /* Generic statement. Can be compound or a single statement */
stmt:compound_stmt
    |single_stmt
    ;

 /* The function body is covered in braces and has multiple statements. */
compound_stmt :'{' statements '}'
    ;

statements:statements stmt
    |
    ;

 /* Grammar for what constitutes every individual statement */
single_stmt :if_block
    |for_block
    |while_block
    |declaration
    |function_call ';'
    |RETURN ';'
    |CONTINUE ';'
    |BREAK ';'
    |RETURN sub_expr ';'
    ;

for_block:FOR '(' expression_stmt  expression_stmt ')' stmt
    |FOR '(' expression_stmt expression_stmt expression ')' stmt
    ;

if_block:IF '(' expression ')' stmt %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE
                |IF '(' expression ')' stmt ELSE stmt
    ;

while_block: WHILE '(' expression   ')' stmt
        ;

declaration:type declaration_list ';'
             |declaration_list ';'
             | unary_expr ';'

declaration_list: declaration_list ',' sub_decl
        |sub_decl;

sub_decl: assignment_expr
    |IDENTIFIER                     {$1 -> data_type = current_dtype;}
    |array_index
    /*|struct_block ';'*/
    ;

/* This is because we can have empty expession statements inside for loops */
expression_stmt:expression ';'
    |';'
    ;

expression:
    expression ',' sub_expr                             {$$ = $1,$3;}
    |sub_expr                                           {$$ = $1;}
        ;

sub_expr:
    sub_expr '>' sub_expr                       {$$ = ($1 > $3);}
    |sub_expr '<' sub_expr                      {$$ = ($1 < $3);}
    |sub_expr EQ sub_expr                       {$$ = ($1 == $3);}
    |sub_expr NOT_EQ sub_expr                   {$$ = ($1 != $3);}
    |sub_expr LS_EQ sub_expr                    {$$ = ($1 <= $3);}
    |sub_expr GR_EQ sub_expr                    {$$ = ($1 >= $3);}
    |sub_expr LOGICAL_AND sub_expr              {$$ = ($1 && $3);}
    |sub_expr LOGICAL_OR sub_expr               {$$ = ($1 || $3);}
    |'!' sub_expr                               {$$ = (!$2);}
    |arithmetic_expr                            {$$ = $1;}
    |assignment_expr                            {$$ = $1;}
    |unary_expr                                 {$$ = $1;}
    /* |IDENTIFIER                                     {$$ = $1->value;}
    |constant                                   {$$ = $1;} */
        //|array_index
    ;


assignment_expr :lhs assign_op arithmetic_expr     {$$ = $1->value = Evaluate($1->value,$2,$3);}
    |lhs assign_op array_index                     {$$ = 0;}
    |lhs assign_op function_call                   {$$ = 0;}
    |lhs assign_op unary_expr                      {$$ = $1->value = Evaluate($1->value,$2,$3);}
    |unary_expr assign_op unary_expr               {$$ = 0;}
    ;

unary_expr: lhs INCREMENT                          {$$ = $1->value = ($1->value)++;}
    |lhs DECREMENT                                 {$$ = $1->value = ($1->value)--;}
    |DECREMENT lhs                                 {$$ = $2->value = --($2->value);}
    |INCREMENT lhs                                 {$$ = $2->value = ++($2->value);}

lhs:IDENTIFIER                                     {$$ = $1; if(! $1->data_type) $1->data_type = current_dtype;}
    //|array_index
    ;

assign_op:'='                                      {$$ = '=';}
    |ADD_ASSIGN                                    {$$ = ADD_ASSIGN;}
    |SUB_ASSIGN                                    {$$ = SUB_ASSIGN;}
    |MUL_ASSIGN                                    {$$ = MUL_ASSIGN;}
    |DIV_ASSIGN                                    {$$ = DIV_ASSIGN;}
    |MOD_ASSIGN                                    {$$ = MOD_ASSIGN;}
    ;

arithmetic_expr: arithmetic_expr '+' arithmetic_expr    {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    |arithmetic_expr '-' arithmetic_expr                {$$ = $1 - $3;}
    |arithmetic_expr '*' arithmetic_expr                {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    |arithmetic_expr '/' arithmetic_expr                {$$ = ($3 == 0) ? yyerror("Divide by 0!") : ($1 / $3);}
    |arithmetic_expr '%' arithmetic_expr                {$$ = (int)$1 % (int)$3;}
    |'(' arithmetic_expr ')'                            {$$ = $2;}
    |'-' arithmetic_expr %prec UMINUS                   {$$ = -$2;}
    |IDENTIFIER                                         {$$ = $1 -> value;}
    |constant                                           {$$ = $1;}
    ;

constant: DEC_CONSTANT                                  {$$ = $1;}
    |HEX_CONSTANT                                       {$$ = $1;}
    ;

array_index: IDENTIFIER '[' sub_expr ']'

function_call: IDENTIFIER '(' parameter_list ')'
             |IDENTIFIER '(' ')'
             ;

parameter_list:
              parameter_list ','  parameter
              |parameter
              ;

parameter: sub_expr
                    |STRING

        ;
%%

#include "lex.yy.c"
#include <ctype.h>


double Evaluate (double lhs_value,int assign_type,double rhs_value)
{
    switch(assign_type)
    {
        case '=': return rhs_value;
        case ADD_ASSIGN: return (lhs_value + rhs_value);
        case SUB_ASSIGN: return (lhs_value - rhs_value);
        case MUL_ASSIGN: return (lhs_value * rhs_value);
        case DIV_ASSIGN: return (lhs_value / rhs_value);
        case MOD_ASSIGN: return ((int)lhs_value % (int)rhs_value);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    symbol_table = create_table();
    constant_table = create_table();

    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!yyparse())
    {
        printf("\nParsing complete\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("\nParsing failed\n");
    }


    printf("\n\tSymbol table");
    display(symbol_table);


    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}

int yyerror(char *msg)
{
    printf("Line no: %d Error message: %s Token: %s\n", yylineno, msg, yytext);
}
```

lexl.l file

```
%{

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

int cmnt_strt = 0;

%}
%option yylineno
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
ws  [ \t\r\f\v]+
identifier (_|{letter})({letter}|{digit}|_){0,31}
hex [0-9a-f]

 /* Exclusive states */
%x CMNT
 /*%x PREPROC*/

%%
  /* Keywords*/
"int"                             {return INT;}
"long"                            {return LONG;}
"long long"                       {return LONG_LONG;}
"short"                           {return SHORT;}
"signed"                          {return SIGNED;}
"unsigned"                        {return UNSIGNED;}
"for"                             {return FOR;}
"while"                           {return WHILE;}
"break"                           {return BREAK;}
"continue"                        {return CONTINUE;}
"if"                              {return IF;}
"else"                            {return ELSE;}
"return"                          {return RETURN;}

{identifier}                      {yylval.entry = insert(symbol_table, yytext, INT_MAX); return  IDENTIFIER;}
{ws}                              ;
[+\-]?[0][x|X]{hex}+[lLuU]?        { yylval.dval = (int)strtol(yytext, NULL, 16); return  HEX_CONSTANT;}
[+\-]?{digit}+[lLuU]?              {yylval.dval = atoi(yytext); return  DEC_CONSTANT;}

"/*"                              {cmnt_strt = yylineno; BEGIN CMNT;}
<CMNT>.|{ws}                      ;
<CMNT>\n                          {yylineno++;}
<CMNT>"*/"                        {BEGIN INITIAL;}
<CMNT>"/*"                        {printf("Line %3d: Nested comments are not valid!\n",yylineno);}
<CMNT><<EOF>>                     {printf("Line %3d: Unterminated comment\n", cmnt_strt); yyterminate();}
 /*^"#include"                       {BEGIN PREPROC;}*/
 /*<PREPROC>"<"[^<>\n]+">"            {return HEADER_FILE;}*/
 /*<PREPROC>{ws}                       ;*/
 /*<PREPROC>\"[^"\n]+\"              {return HEADER_FILE;}*/
 /*<PREPROC>\n                       {yylineno++; BEGIN INITIAL;}*/
 /*<PREPROC>.                        {printf("Line %3d: Illegal header file format \n",yylineno);}*/
"//".*                            ;

\"[^\"\n]*\"     {

  if(yytext[yyleng-2]=='\\') /* check if it was an escaped quote */
  {
    yyless(yyleng-1);       /* push the quote back if it was escaped */
    yymore();
  }
  else{
  insert( constant_table, yytext, INT_MAX);
  return STRING;
  }
 }

\"[^\"\n]*$                     {printf("Line %3d: Unterminated string %s\n",yylineno,yytext);}
{digit}+({letter}|_)+           {printf("Line %3d: Illegal identifier name %s\n",yylineno,yytext);}
\n                              {yylineno++;}

"--"                            {return DECREMENT;}
"++"                            {return INCREMENT;}
 /* "->"                            {return PTR_SELECT;} */
"+="                      {return ADD_ASSIGN;}
"-="                      {return SUB_ASSIGN;}
"*="                      {return MUL_ASSIGN;}
"/="                      {return DIV_ASSIGN;}
"%="                      {return MOD_ASSIGN;}


"&&"                            {return LOGICAL_AND;}
"||"                            {return LOGICAL_OR;}
"<="                            {return LS_EQ;}
">="                            {return GR_EQ;}
"=="                            {return EQ;}
"!="                          {return NOT_EQ;}

.                         {return yytext[0];}

%%
/*
int main()
{
  yyin=fopen("test2.c","r");

  constant_table=create_table();
  symbol_table = create_table();

  yylex();

  printf("\n\tSymbol table");
  display(symbol_table);
  printf("\n\tConstants Table");
  display(constant_table);

  printf("NOTE: Please refer tokens.h for token meanings\n");
} */
```

symboltable.h file

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HASH_TABLE_SIZE 100

/* struct to hold each entry */
struct entry_s
{
    char* lexeme;
    double value;
    int data_type;
    struct entry_s* successor;
};

typedef struct entry_s entry_t;

/* Create a new hash_table. */
entry_t** create_table()
{
    entry_t** hash_table_ptr = NULL; // declare a pointer

    /* Allocate memory for a hashtable array of size HASH_TABLE_SIZE */
    if( ( hash_table_ptr = malloc( sizeof( entry_t* ) * HASH_TABLE_SIZE ) ) == NULL )
        return NULL;

    int i;

    // Intitialise all entries as NULL
    for( i = 0; i < HASH_TABLE_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        hash_table_ptr[i] = NULL;
    }

    return hash_table_ptr;
}

/* Generate hash from a string. Then generate an index in [0, HASH_TABLE_SIZE) */
uint32_t hash( char *lexeme )
{
    size_t i;
    uint32_t hash;

    /* Apply jenkin's hash function
    * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function#one-at-a-time
    */
    for ( hash = i = 0; i < strlen(lexeme); ++i ) {
        hash += lexeme[i];
        hash += ( hash << 10 );
        hash ^= ( hash >> 6 );
    }
    hash += ( hash << 3 );
    hash ^= ( hash >> 11 );
    hash += ( hash << 15 );

    return hash % HASH_TABLE_SIZE; // return an index in [0, HASH_TABLE_SIZE)
}

/* Create an entry for a lexeme, token pair. This will be called from the insert function */
entry_t *create_entry( char *lexeme, int value )
{
    entry_t *newentry;

    /* Allocate space for newentry */
    if( ( newentry = malloc( sizeof( entry_t ) ) ) == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Copy lexeme to newentry location using strdup (string-duplicate). Return NULL if it fails */
    if( ( newentry->lexeme = strdup( lexeme ) ) == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newentry->value = value;
    newentry->successor = NULL;

    return newentry;
}

/* Search for an entry given a lexeme. Return a pointer to the entry of the lexeme exists, else return NULL */
entry_t* search( entry_t** hash_table_ptr, char* lexeme )
{
    uint32_t idx = 0;
    entry_t* myentry;

    // get the index of this lexeme as per the hash function
    idx = hash( lexeme );

    /* Traverse the linked list at this idx and see if lexeme exists */
    myentry = hash_table_ptr[idx];

    while( myentry != NULL && strcmp( lexeme, myentry->lexeme ) != 0 )
    {
        myentry = myentry->successor;
    }

    if(myentry == NULL) // lexeme is not found
        return NULL;

    else // lexeme found
        return myentry;

}

/* Insert an entry into a hash table. */
entry_t* insert( entry_t** hash_table_ptr, char* lexeme, int value )
{
    entry_t* finder = search( hash_table_ptr, lexeme );
    if( finder != NULL) // If lexeme already exists, don't insert, return
        return finder ;

    uint32_t idx;
    entry_t* newentry = NULL;
    entry_t* head = NULL;

    idx = hash( lexeme ); // Get the index for this lexeme based on the hash function
    newentry = create_entry( lexeme, value ); // Create an entry using the <lexeme, token> pair

    if(newentry == NULL) // In case there was some error while executing create_entry()
    {
        printf("Insert failed. New entry could not be created.");
        exit(1);
    }

    head = hash_table_ptr[idx]; // get the head entry at this index

    if(head == NULL) // This is the first lexeme that matches this hash index
    {
        hash_table_ptr[idx] = newentry;
    }
    else // if not, add this entry to the head
    {
        newentry->successor = hash_table_ptr[idx];
        hash_table_ptr[idx] = newentry;
    }
    return hash_table_ptr[idx];
}

// Traverse the hash table and print all the entries
void display(entry_t** hash_table_ptr)
{
    int i;
    entry_t* traverser;
    printf("\n====================================================\n");
    printf(" %-20s %-20s %-20s\n","lexeme","value","data-type");
    printf("====================================================\n");

    for( i=0; i < HASH_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        traverser = hash_table_ptr[i];

        while( traverser != NULL)
        {
            printf(" %-20s %-20d %-20d \n", traverser->lexeme, (int)traverser->value, traverser->data_type);
            traverser = traverser->successor;
        }
    }
    printf("====================================================\n");

}
```

I cant figure out why unknown file type error is given. If you can please point me in the right direction.

Comment: A header file like `symboltable.h` should not normally include the implementations of the function.  It should only include their declarations and a separate source file `symboltable.c` should define the functions.  There are exceptions to the rule (do example, `static inline` functions) but they don't really apply here.

Comment: Is it the C compiler complaining or Yacc/Bison complaining?

Comment: C compiler @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are the same Shehan who yesterday asked [this question with remarkably similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198411/lexical-analyzer-gives-undefined-error-for-yylineno), what I said then still applies:

> If this is the first time you've attempted to write a C application with more than one source file, you should probably take a few minutes to review how linking multiple files works in C. That will save you a lot of frustration later.

This is precisely the sort of frustration I was referring to.

The error you are receiving comes from attempting to compile `lex.yy.c`. That file, which is generated from `lexl.l`, does not `#include "symboltable.h"`, but it does `#include "y.tab.h"`. In `y.tab.h`, `entry_t` is used in the declaration of the `union` semantic type, but since `symboltable.h` has not been included, `entry_t` has not been defined.

But just adding `#include "symboltable.h"` won't work, so please don't do it.

`symboltable.h` is not a correct header file, as has been mentioned in [a comment by @JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203865/parser-gives-a-unknown-type-name-error-for-entry-t#comment122315066_69203865). Header files must not contain function definitions, only declarations. Furthermore, `symboltable.h` does not have inclusion guards, so nothing stops it from being included twice, resulting in duplicate definition errors.

But the way your files are set up, you shouldn't be compiling `lex.yy.c` in the first place. Your `parser.y` file includes the line

```
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

which, as might be expected, includes the entire text of `lex.yy.c` in the source being compiled when you compile `y.tab.c`. I don't believe you thought this trick up yourself; I think you copied it from some tutorial written by someone who was too lazy to attempt to explain how to set up a project with multiple sources. Although it is possible to make things work for simple parsers, it's not going to serve you well in the future, and you should not start your learning about parsers by learning bad habits.

So I say once again: please start by learning how to create a C project with multiple source and header files. Otherwise, your attempt to learn how to use bison and flex will be much harder and more frustrating than necessary.

Comment: Any good text on C programming should contain a section on how to divide your project into multiple files. If your text does not contain a that information, find a better one.

Comment: Anyway that you can teach me? Tutoring or anything. I'm eager to learn this but not finding the right resources to go any further. My lecture sucks and he doesn't do practical he only does theory. thank anyway.

Comment: @ShehanFernando: If I find some time on Sunday, I'll try to write something. I couldn't find a good online teaching resource, but I'm sure there are textbooks (starting with K&R). But no promises. I definitely don't have time to take on a student, sorry.

Comment: Thats fine. Thanks alot for considering :)